# Side by Side Div's not aligning up

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've been searching all day for a solution.  There might be one but I don't understand the explanations that are being given of CSS and DIV's.

A link or assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to place DIV's side by side in a wrapper and I can't figure out why they don't line up.

Thank You for your Assistance.
~Donavon

Left Heading = 75% and Right Heading = 25% so that should equal 100% of the wrapper which is 95%.  But the Right Heading is wrapping.

AND

the Left, Middle and Right portlet sections should align up on the same row..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test-columns</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    #buttons {
       border:             1px solid;
       text-align:         center;
       width:              95%;
       margin:             0 auto;
    }


    #container_heading {
       border:             1px solid;
       width:              95%;
       text-align:         center;
       margin:             0 auto;
    }

    #left_heading {
      border:             1px solid;
      float:              left;
      width:              75%;
      text-align:         center;
      margin:             0; 
      padding:            0;
    }

    #right_heading {
      border:             1px solid;
      float:              right;
      width:              25%;  
      text-align:         center;
      margin:             0; 
      padding:            0;
    }


    #controls {
      clear:              both;
      border:             1px solid;
      text-align:         center;
      width:              95%;
      margin:             0 auto;
    }



    #sections {
      border:             1px solid;
      margin:             0px auto;
      width:              95%;
    }

    #left_portlets {
      border:             1px solid;
      text-align:         center;
      float:              left;
      width:              33%;
      margin:             0 auto;
    }

    #middle_portlets {
      border:             1px solid;
      text-align:         center;
      width:              33%;
      margin:             0 auto;
    }

    #right_portlets {
      border:             1px solid;
      text-align:         center;
      float:              right;
      width:              33%;
      margin:             0 auto;
    }


</style>



</head>

<body style="margin: 0" >

  <div id="buttons"> 
    Buttons
  </div>

  <br /><br />


  <div id="container_heading">   
    <div id="left_heading"> 
      Left Heading
    </div>

    <div id="right_heading"> 
      Right Heading
    </div>
  </div>  

  <br /><br />

  <div id="controls"> 
    Controls
  </div>

  <br /><br />


  <div id="sections">
    <div id="left_portlets">
      <div id="1-1_portlet">
        1-1 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="1-2_portlet">
        1-2 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="1-3_portlet">
        1-3 Portlet
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle_portlets">
      <div id="2-1_portlet">
        2-1 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="2-2_portlet">
        2-2 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="2-3_portlet">
        2-3 Portlet
      </div>    
    </div>

    <div id="right_portlets">
      <div id="3-1_portlet">
        3-1 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="3-2_portlet">
        3-2 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="3-3_portlet">
        3-3 Portlet
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

EDIT:
Wow.  This helped alot...

I took away a percentage point from the widths to compensate for the borders and added "display:inline-block;" to the div that line up next to each other and "box-sizing:border-box;" to the whole style sheet.

Things are now lining up on the rows.  But now how do I even up the outside margins so everything is square?  Every time I make a little change the layout breaks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test-columns</title>

<style type="text/css">
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
* { -moz-box-sizing:    border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing:         border-box; }


#buttons {
  border:             1px solid;
  text-align:         center;
  width:              95%;
  margin:             0 auto;
}


#container_heading {
  border:             0px;
  width:              95%;
  text-align:         center;
  margin:             0 auto;
}

#left_heading {
  border:             1px solid;
  width:              74%;
  text-align:         center;
  margin:             0; 
  padding:            0;
  display:            inline-block;
}

#right_heading {
  border:             1px solid;
  width:              24%;  
  text-align:         center;
  margin:             0; 
  padding:            0;
  display:            inline-block;
}


#controls {
  clear:              both;
  border:             1px solid;
  text-align:         center;
  width:              95%;
  margin:             0 auto;

}

#sections {
  border:             0px;
  margin:             0px auto;
  width:              95%;
  text-align:         center;
}

#left_portlets {
  border:             1px solid;
  text-align:         center;
  width:              31%;
  margin:             0 auto;
  display:            inline-block;
}

#middle_portlets {
  border:             1px solid;
  text-align:         center;
  width:              31%;
  margin:             0 auto;
  display:            inline-block;
}

#right_portlets {
  border:             1px solid;
  text-align:         center;
  width:              31%;
  margin:             0 auto;
  display:            inline-block;
}

</style>



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0" >

  <div id="buttons"> 
    Buttons
  </div>




  <div id="container_heading">   
    <div id="left_heading"> 
      Left Heading
    </div>

    <div id="right_heading"> 
      Right Heading
    </div>
  </div>  



  <div id="controls"> 
    Controls
  </div>




  <div id="sections">
    <div id="left_portlets">
      <div id="1-1_portlet">
        1-1 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="1-2_portlet">
        1-2 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="1-3_portlet">
        1-3 Portlet
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="middle_portlets">
      <div id="2-1_portlet">
        2-1 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="2-2_portlet">
        2-2 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="2-3_portlet">
        2-3 Portlet
      </div>    
    </div>

    <div id="right_portlets">
      <div id="3-1_portlet">
        3-1 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="3-2_portlet">
        3-2 Portlet
      </div>

      <div id="3-3_portlet">
        3-3 Portlet
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the border causing the issue, as it adds to the size of the box (75% + 2px, 1px for each side). You can include this:

```
#left_heading,#right_heading,[anything else %-width and has borders] {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This will correct it by having the box conform to the width proscribed including the border, but please note it will only work for IE8+ (and obviously the standards-compliant ones). IE7- you will need to include [some crazy shim](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill). This is a good policy to [apply to everything](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), as it will save a lot of headaches with CSS on block items.

Something else you might want to consider is using `display:inline-block;` rather than floats. This falls into the same scope as `box-sizing:border-box;` (only applies to IE8+, however there is an IE7- fallback of `zoom:1; *display:inline;` that works the same), however it creates far more customizability options in the future. What if you added a new header? Now you need to change your widths AND your floats ... but if everything is inline-block, you can just change the widths and you're golden. You could also then assign the display in one class declaration, rather than different floats for different placements of items.

Just food for thought.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this article but couldn't find it. I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the borders (that's pushing it over 100%) and Float the middle squares too.

Once you do that they all fall into place...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your use of border styling in combination with the width, as the border extends around the outside of the element.  Since the combined width of your elements in a row add up to 100%, applying a border forces it to adjust so all of the elements can fit on a page.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem you should erase the `border` because border also effect your width having `1px` in the `right and left` it became to `2px` equivalent `4px` in two box that the cause why the box are not align, becasue you already have a 100% width and there is no space for 4px.

to make the two div align you should eliminate the `border` or adjust your `width`

```
 #left_heading {
          float:              left;
          width:              75%;
          text-align:         center;
          margin:             0; 
          padding:            0;
        }

    #right_heading {
      float:              right;
      width:              25%;  
      text-align:         center;
      margin:             0; 
      padding:            0;
    }
```